# Sequence in Number Theory, at Madhava 2020

Tags: number-theory

Let $a_{1} , a_{2},....$ be sequence of natural numbers, such that $gcd(a_{m}, a_{n})=gcd(m,n)$ for $m$ not equals $n$. Then show that $a_{n}=n$ for all natural numbers $n$.

I am looking for an alternative approach.

My approach.
Suppose $r\geq 2$ then take $m=rn$ thus $n=gcd(rn,n)=gcd(a_{rn}, a_{n})$ thus $n|a_{n}$ now the idea is to show that $v_{p}(n)=v_{p}(a_{n})$ for every prime $p$ dividing $n$ or  $a_{n}$ as $n|a_{n}$ assume that $v_{p}(a_{n})\geq v_{p}(n)$ then take a $s$ large enough and then set $m=p^{v_{p}(a_{n})}s$ then 
$p^{v_{p}(a_{n})} | gcd(a_{m}, a_{n})=gcd(m,n)$ thus 
$p^{v_{p}(a_{n})}| n$ thus  $v_{p}(a_{n})\leq v_{p}(n)$ thus $v_{p}(n)=v_{p}(a_{n})$ and we are done.

Comment: Also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752370/math-olympiads-gcd-of-terms-in-a-sequence-equals-gcd-of-terms-in-other-sequence) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751094/math-olympiads-gcd-of-terms-in-a-sequence-equals-gcd-of-their-indices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An alternative approach**

For any natural number $m$, $\text{gcd}(a_m,a_{2m})=\text{gcd}(m,2m)=m$
and so each $a_m$ is a multiple of $m$.

Suppose that there is an $n$ such that $a_n=kn$ where $k>1$. Then both $a_n$ and $a_{kn}$ are multiples of $kn$ contradicting the fact that  $\text{gcd}(a_n,a_{kn})=\text{gcd}(n,kn)=n$.

Hence all $a_n=n$.

Comment: Thanks it's more easy!!! Wow!!!. Initially I don't know the  problem was already here in mse, sorry for duplicating it, to the one who marked it duplicate.